# How do I partition an SD drive that is greater than 4GB so that ubuntu runs on 4GB and the rest is used as storage?

Tags: installation, sd-card

I've been trying for about a week now to partition my 32GB SD Card so 4GB can be used as a Ubuntu Live and the rest as general storage that can be seen by Ubuntu and Windows.

I've tried this method:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/
Everything works up until the Start Disk Creator. My partitions are not visible there even though they are visible on my computer.

Also I've attempted with VM Player
http://www.howtogeek.com/97177/how-to-put-ubuntu-linux-on-a-usb-thumb-drive-without-the-mess/

If this helps, here is the SD card I'm using with the USB adapter.
http://www.adorama.com/KGMB10G232GB.html?utm_term=Other&utm_medium=Shopping%20Site&utm_campaign=Other&utm_source=gbase

Comment: Are you trying to use the SD card as a Hard Drive?

Comment: Are both partitions on the SD card FAT32?

Comment: This question/answers may be what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Comment: @Mitch No, I don't think so. I'm trying to make a bootable SD card I can use on any computer but have my settings and programs saved. But have the remainder as storage viewable by all devices or OS. I don't think I'm doing a full install. But I will try what TenPlus1 had mentioned.

Comment: @TomBrossman No. NTFS for the open storage. EXT2 for Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SD card as a hard-drive to boot from then during install you would make a 5 GB `/` partition and put the rest in `/home`...  you need room for the OS to breathe and update and all that shabang but their are tweaks available to move most of that work into memory and save SD usage...